# Why can't I seem to put a Label into a StackLayout (or other Layouts) within a Kivy-App?

Tags: python, kivy

In theory, putting a Kivy-[Label](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html) into a [Stack Layout](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.stacklayout.html) (or into some other layout) should be the easiest and most common thing - but it is currently plunging me into despair. The following syntax displays a plain single-button app (under Kivy 1.8 or 1.9, Win 7) *until I uncomment the Label-generating line*, which consistently fails with messages such as `AttributeError: 'LabelPygame' object has no attribute 'bind'` or `AttributeError: 'LabelSDL2' object has no attribute 'bind'` (in `layout.py`):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.text import Label
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        mylayout = StackLayout(orientation='lr-tb')
        mylayout.add_widget(Button(text='This button can always be rendered.'))
        # mylayout.add_widget(Label(text='This label seems to cause trouble.'))
        return mylayout

TestApp().run()
```

I have a hunch that I am overlooking something really-really obvious or silly, but cannot get at what it is. An alternative invocation based on the `Builder` and `runTouchApp` appears to work just fine (the kind of Layout did not seem to make a difference):

```
# ... other imports abbreviated ... 

Builder.load_string('''
<MyLayout>:
    Button:
        text: "This button can always be rendered."
    Label:
        text: "This label works in this case."
''')

class MyLayout(FloatLayout):
    pass

runTouchApp(MyLayout())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're importing `kivy.core.text.Label`, but you really want `kivy.uix.label.Label`.

Comment: This hurts, but it's nice when the pain abates! Switching to `from kivy.uix.xyzlayout import XyzLayout` anyway solved the problem. Thanks for pointing me to the nature of my blunder, which might have saved me from some more hours of screen-staring...